# How could I separate email using Python MIME multipart?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, email, mime, python-sockets

Sending an email using sockets. I want to separate plain text and attachment. I use MIME multipart/mixed; boundary.

```
cSockSSL.send("MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".encode())
cSockSSL.send("Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=gg4g5gg\r\n".encode())
cSockSSL.send("--gg4g5gg".encode('ascii'))

cSockSSL.send("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n".encode())
cSockSSL.send("Some text".encode())
cSockSSL.send("--gg4g5gg".encode())

cSockSSL.send("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n".encode())
cSockSSL.send("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = gg.txt\r\n".encode())
cSockSSL.send(txt_file)
cSockSSL.send("--gg4g5gg--".encode())
cSockSSL.send("\r\n.\r\n".encode())
```

In this case, I get an empty email with the header. If I delete first boundary I'll get this:

> Some text--gg4g5ggContent-Type: text/plain
> Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = gg.txt
> Hey! I'm txt file!--gg4g5gg--

How to correctly split content-type?

Comment: Rather than doing everything from scratch, is there a reason why you are not using Python's built-in email and MIME features?

Comment: Using raw SSL to transmit a message seems completely crazy. Embedding the message as a sequence of strings in the sending code itself, doubly so. If you really have to, `for line in emailmessage.as_string().split("\n"): cSockSSL.send(line + "\n")` where `emailmessage` is the result of `from email import EmailMessage; emailmessage = EmailMessage()` etc etc where you would then build the message in accordance with the [examples from the `email` documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your email data is malformed, as you are missing several required line breaks.

Per [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822), you need to separate the email's headers from the email's body using `\r\n\r\n` instead of `\r\n`.

And per [RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045), you need to separate MIME headers from MIME bodies using `\r\n\r\n` instead of `\r\n`. And, you are missing `\r\n` in front of each MIME boundary that follows a text body, and after each MIME boundary.

So, essentially, you are sending an email that looks like this, all squished together:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=gg4g5gg
--gg4g5ggContent-Type: text/plain
Some text--gg4g5ggContent-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = gg.txt
<txt_file>--gg4g5gg--
.
```

But it needs to look more like this instead:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=gg4g5gg

--gg4g5gg
Content-Type: text/plain

Some text
--gg4g5gg
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = gg.txt

<txt_file>
--gg4g5gg--
.
```

So, try this instead:

```py
cSockSSL.send("DATA\r\n".encode())
# verify response is 354...

cSockSSL.send("MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".encode())
cSockSSL.send("Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=gg4g5gg\r\n".encode())
cSockSSL.send("\r\n".encode()) # add a line break

cSockSSL.send("--gg4g5gg\r\n".encode('ascii')) # add a line break
cSockSSL.send("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n".encode())
cSockSSL.send("\r\n".encode()) # add a line break
cSockSSL.send("Some text".encode())

cSockSSL.send("\r\n--gg4g5gg\r\n".encode()) # add line breaks
cSockSSL.send("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n".encode())
cSockSSL.send("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=gg.txt\r\n".encode())
cSockSSL.send("\r\n".encode()) # add a line break
cSockSSL.send(txt_file)
cSockSSL.send("\r\n--gg4g5gg--\r\n".encode()) # add line breaks

cSockSSL.send(".\r\n".encode())
```

Something else to be aware of - because the `DATA` command terminator is `.\r\n`, if `"Some text"` or `txt_file` contain any lines that begin with the `.` character, you MUST escape each leading `.` as `..`, per [RFC 2821 Section 4.5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821#section-4.5.2).

I suggest you study the RFCs mentioned above more carefully.